# Definition the term "routing" used in angularJS tutorial?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

In the below page near the top the writer does a good job of describing all the puzzle pieces Angular makes up in a web app, but there was just one that I wasn't able to find a good source of information on:

- routing

Searches are tough - either revealing just some kind of framework or concep specific to a back-end or low level framework or language so I'm not sure about using these as an introduction.  And/or they assume the user knows what all this entails before beginning.  Is this a well known OOP concept or is it specific to javascript/front end development?  If it's network routing, such as this (http://www.google.com/patents/US20030046422) I'd be happy to read through it, but I'm not sure if this is actually it.  I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer - that includes all the things that make up "routing" especially clientside/with JS as I thought this was more of a backend/low level concept.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/overview

```
Everything you need to build a CRUD app in a cohesive set: data-binding, basic templating directives, form validation, routing, deep-linking, reusable components, dependency injection.
```

Comment: Alxandr is correct, routing in the SPA world refers to mapping URLs to views/templates/pages.

Comment: SPA stands for Single Page Application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routing in AngularJS (at least as far as I've understand) refers to the action of taking a URL in the browser, and mapping that to a controller and view.

For instance, you can set up that the url: `/admin` runs the `AdminCtrl`-controller and loads the view `/partials/admin.html`. When I say load view, I don't mean that the browser refreshes to the page `/partials/admin.html`, rather it loads it in the background (using AJAX I presume, or an IFrame, or some other means of acquiring it), and when it has the data it compiles it (as angular does with the page), and runs it against the scope given to the `AdminCtrl`-controller. It then inserts the result into any `ng-view`-directive on the page.

Comment: Doesn't always need to be done on the back-end I suppose, although this doesn't seem to be a great way to handle mobile.  I guess I will find out?